# Is there a way to insert row/column in matrix (Eigen C++)?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using the Eigen library in C++.
I need to insert a row and column to an existing matrix at specific index.

For example, say I need to insert a 0 row and 0 column at the 2nd index...

ORIGINAL MATRIX (A)

1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

NEW MATRIX (B)

1 2 0 3
1 2 0 3
0 0 0 0
1 2 0 3

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The new matrix `B` can be constructed from the original matrix `A` by using the [block operations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialBlockOperations.html) `.topRows()` and `.bottomRows()`:

```
  MatrixXd B = MatrixXd::Zero(4, 3);
  B.topRows(2) = A.topRows(2);
  B.bottomRows(1) =  A.bottomRows(1);
```

This will insert a row  of zeros between the second and third row. Analogous operations with `.rightCols()` and `.leftCols()` can be used to insert a column of zeros.